# Is it possible to open docx files that have been saved in Ubuntu's LibreOffice in Microsoft Office?

Tags: libreoffice

Here's exactly what I mean by that. Let's say I pulled a Microsoft Office docx file off the Web. I know I can easily open it up in LibreOffice and make changes to it. I'm also able to save it. If I take that file now and try to open it in Microsoft Office, will I see all my changes that I made to it in LibreOffice without MIcrosoft Office complaining?

Comment: "and try to open it in Microsoft Office" That is a Windows related question ;-)  "not going to complain?" It basically depends on what you did with the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, and no.

Yes, LibreOffice and MS Office both support the docx format.

However, LibreOffice and MS Office are not necessarily using the same fonts, so documents may look different as a result. LibreOffice also doesn't necessarily handle all the things that may be embedded in the document, nor any macros, so opening in LO and then saving back out, may lose some data which cannot be handled.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible :
DOCX is handled by LibreOffice.

Meanwhile, some formatting functions are not compatible between both "offices".
Sometimes, some colors applied will not being seen in each other.

Comment: There are far more issues between the 2 ;-)

Comment: So, basically, it's better to avoid using LibreOffice if you're going to work primarily with docx files?

Comment: I would say yes, unfortunately. The other solution, if you collaborate with people using MS office is to just send them pictures/text changes separately and let them format it in MS office. But for simple documents, using libreoffice to generate docx files might be fine. You can always use the free document viewers provided by MS to check what it will look like in there. I had success running some of the older ones using Wine.

Answer (score 1):

Saving as .docx in LibreOffice might work, but I often find problems.  Instead, there are two more reliable methods on Linux:

1. In LibreOffice, make changes and then save as PDF.  People using windows will be able to view the changes with 100% accuracy but will not be able to make their own changes.
2. Use [MS Office online](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-online/documents-spreadsheets-presentations-office-online).  It's free.